# Looking for writer's platform

Tags: publishing, software, tools

I'm looking for a platform (web app, saas application) to manage writers and articles for a large blog. I'm looking for the following features:

1. I enter topics, writers can claim subjects and write about it. First come, first get, who claims it first will write about it. Other writers can see which topics have been claimed.
2. Allows me to create a list of topics for writers to pick from (only visible to writers I invited to my pool).
3. A list of new topics is automatically sent from the web app by email to each writer on a daily base.
4. I can easily invite new people to join my pool of writers.
5. I can rate writer's articles.
6. When an article is ready, I can publish it to Wordpress.
7. Each writer can set pricing per article, per word, per hour,...
8. Writers can suggest topics, which the admin needs to approve first.

Does such a platform exist? Or how do you tackle this workflow?

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Trello](https://trello.com/) which I believe will support everything you want (except the daily posting of topics, and even that should  not be too difficult to automate).

It is a project management tool for teams that allows you to define any categories you wish for tasks (such as new topics, claimed topics, drafts submitted, payment negotiated, published etc) and to move individual tasks between them. A task can be defined by a short description, an image, a checklist, an attached file or all of the above.

Trello is free to use.

Comment: We use Trello for everything from our business to our home life. It's fast and easy to use with a loose style that makes it easy to work the way you want. Plus there are Android and Windows apps for it.

Answer (score 0):

This website can serve your purpose : http://writersplatform.net/

Also, some important points to be considered while building a writer's platform can be known from this website :

1) http://www.yourwriterplatform.com/actions-to-build-writer-platform/

2) http://writeabetternovel.net/a-writer%E2%80%99s-platform-want-to-publish-start-building-yours/

3) http://emeryroad.com/4-keys-to-building-a-writers-platform/